# Spring, JXLS : XLS transformer not loaded, even though dependency exists.

Tags: java, excel, spring, maven, jxls

I am trying my hands on [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html) which is a Java library for creating excel files, and other operations with it in a Spring-MVC project. When I try to create a excel-file out of some data, I get the following error :

Error log :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath
    at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.createTransformer(JxlsHelper.java:200)
    at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.processTemplateAtCell(JxlsHelper.java:118)
    at com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupNotesServiceImpl.saveGroupNotesToExcel(GroupNotesServiceImpl.java:917)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
```

Code :

```
   @Override
    public void saveGroupNotesToExcel(int msectionid){
        List<GroupNotes> groupNotesList = this.groupNotesDAO.listGroupNotesBySectionId(msectionid);
            try(InputStream is = GroupNotesServiceImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/home/path/to/jls/test.xls")) {
                try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/home/path/to/jls/output.xls")) {
                    Context context = new Context();
                    context.putVar("groupNotesList", groupNotesList);
                    JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplateAtCell(is, os, context, "Result!A1");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Here is my POM.xml with the dependencies :

```
  <!-- Excel dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I checked other answers on net, but there was only 1 of missing dependency, which I already have. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The problem that I was having was for whatever reason, getting a resource as a stream would not work. It would always return null.

Changing my code to get the input stream to this solved my problem:

```
URL fileResource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MyTemplate.xlsx");

File file = new File(fileResource.toURI());

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

My recommendation if this does not solve your problem, is to debug into the jxls code and see where it's returning the null and make sure none of the other inputs are null at that point. This error just means that a valid transformer was not able to be constructed, not that one doesn't exist on the class path. I have no idea why they made the exception so misleading.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem too, and my template file placed under  src/main/resources.

After I changed the code from

```
InputStream is = JxlsTest.class.getResourceAsStream("object_collection_template.xls");
```

(above code cannot read the template file)
to

```
InputStream is = JxlsTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/object_collection_template.xls");
```

this error disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Java:

```
List<Employee> employees = initEmployees();
try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/Yasin/Downloads/template.xlsx"));
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/Yasin/Downloads/formulas_output.xlsx"));
    Context context = new Context();
    context.putVar("employees", employees);
    JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplateAtCell(is, os, context, "Result!A1");

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

XML:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my dependencies for reading and write Excel docs, try it

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Sorry, still the same error at JxlsHelper.getInstance. I even ran a mvn clean && mvn install before starting the project, but no luck.

Comment: jxls can use only one implementation poi or jexcel, so you need to decide which one to use. I'm using poi now.

Comment: I don't know which one I am using unfortunately.  How can I determine that? I don't have anything POI other than jxls-poi in pom.xml, I searched it.

Comment: Can you tell me how and which one to use? Thank you!

Comment: try to remove or comment dependency block in xml with jxls-jexcel and jxls-reader. make mvn clean install

Comment: I kept only one dependency i.e org.jxl's jxls with version 2.2.8. Still no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101580/discussion-between-vladimir-dergachev-and-we-are-borg).

Comment: Problem solved after using Apache-POI. Thank you for your effort as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tried a lot and solved the issues but adding the below List of dependency JAR used to solve this issue

1. 1.commons-codec-1.10.jar
   2.commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   3.commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
   4.commons-logging-1.2.jar
   5.jxls-2.4.0.jar
   6.jxls-jexcel-1.0.6.jar
   7.jxls-poi-1.0.12.jar
   8.jxls-reader-2.0.2.jar
   9.poi-3.14.jar
   10.poi-ooxml-3.15.jar
   11.slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar